# Integrate jQuery Datepicker into Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I have the `gem 'jquery-rails'` installed via Gemfile and I have the following in application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

and I'm trying to integrate the following code into Rails 3:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

I should be able to just copy it into my view (ERB) and it should work correct?

Comment: what's the problem you are having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to include jquery UI - http://jqueryui.com/. That will also include a CSS file for styling the date picker widget, so don't forget that too.

Comment: For anyone else that happens upon this: I followed the directions here: https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails and it worked. Essentially add gem to Gemfile, modify application.js and application.css and you're good to go.